# Django REST Custom View Parameters in Viewset with CoreAPI

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

If I define a django-rest-framework view framework as:

```
class ProblemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Problem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProblemSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=(permissions.IsAuthenticated,))
    def submit(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # my code here
        return Response(...)
```

When I look at the CoreAPI schema that is defined, I find this:

```
problems: {
    create(title, text, value, category, hint)
    destroy(pk)
    list([page])
    partial_update(pk, [title], [text], [value], [category], [hint])
    retrieve(pk)
    submit(pk)
    update(pk, title, text, value, category, hint)
}
```

I'd like the `submit` API endpoint to take an additional parameter, called `answer`, but so far I haven't figured out how to add such a custom parameter. I know I can just pass in the POST array, but that seems inelegant and un-RESTful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question, but I think that you want to add in the input the filed `answer` to django-rest form or raw, you can do this adding in the serializer `ProblemSerializer` the next:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
...
class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    answer = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    class Meta:
        model = Problem
        fields = ['answer', 'my-normal-params',...]

def get_answer(self, problem):
    if hasattr(problem, 'answer'):
        request = self.context['request']
        return answer
```

In get_answer method you will display in the json the value that you want, or you can return None (null) if you want,

If that is not your problem, please say me, I'll help you.

Comment: what happens if I only want to use the 'answer' field in one of the views that uses ProblemSerializer? when I do this, it adds 'answer' to every API endpoint in that viewset. do I have to create another serializer?

Comment: umm... in that case I think that this link could help you http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#creating-custom-mixins Also I have not test this, I don't know if this could work buy you can overwrite the attribute ´serializer_class´ inside of `get_queryset` method, adding your custom serializer depends of the url, or also un you can add inside yout `detatil_view` something like this: `self.serializer_class = ProblemSubmitSerializer`.

Comment: okay, good idea, you can pass a serializer_class argument to @detail_route. thanks!